# Como retornar uma mensagem junto com um HttpStatusCode

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Tenho o seguinte método em meu `Controller`:

```
public IHttpActionResult Get(string id) 
    {
        var product = objds.GetProduct(new ObjectId(id));
        if (product == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return Ok(product);
    }
```

Se o produto for `null` então retorno um `404`, caso contrário retorno um `OK` com o produto. Minhas dúvidas são as seguintes:

- Como posso retornar uma mensagem junto com o status `404`?
- Tem algum problema em retornar uma mensagem junto com o `status`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Como posso retornar uma mensagem junto com o status 404?

De uma maneira simples, basta fazer isso:

```
return Content(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Foo does not exist.");
```

#### Tem algum problema em retornar uma mensagem junto com o status?

Não existe problemas com isso. O que ocorre geralmente é que você obtém a resposta ao fazer uma requisição à uma API. Agora, se quer enviar uma mensagem junto, pode fazer.

Existem outras formas de implementar esta mesma funcionalidade, como mostrado [nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20139621/4843158)