# Retornar mensagem junto com UnauthorizedResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, .net-core

Estou usando .NET Core 2 para criar uma dependência que será injetada em uma API. A ideia é criar um *middleware* para controlar as requisições que chegam e atuar de acordo com uma série de regras de negócio. Vale apontar que não posso alterar a API em si, por isso o *approach* escolhido foi esse. Para tal, estou implementando a interface `IActionFilter`

```
public class RequestsFilter: IActionFilter
{

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        // code
    }


    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        // code
    }
}
```

Em um caso de uso simples, preciso bloquear as requisições não autorizadas pela falta do *token* necessário. Consigo retornar o código HTTP correspondente da seguinte maneira:

```
 public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
 {
     var _token = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"];

     if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(_token))
     {
         context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
     }
 }
```

Sem entrar no mérito de validação do *token*, isso é o suficiente para que a minha requisição seja bloqueada. Porém, preciso que, junto com o código 401, um *JSON* contendo uma mensagem de erro seja retornado, algo como

```
{
    "error": "unauthorized"
}
```

Tentei seguir [essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/135369/como-retornar-uma-mensagem-junto-com-um-httpstatuscode), porém o equivalente de `Content` no Core  -
 pelo menos até onde eu sei - não recebe parâmetros no construtor. O construtor de `UnauthorizedResult` também não. Tentei criar a minha resposta manualmente, algo na linha de:

```
context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 401;
// ...
```

Mas o retorno continua sendo 200, e a requisição ocorre sem problemas. O que estou fazendo de errado? O que está faltando? Como faço para retornar o código adequado e a mensagem de erro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

crie um ObjectResult, com ele vc pode retornar qualquer objeto junto ao código de erro.

```
var result = new ObjectResult(new{erro ="você precisa ser admin"});  
result.StatusCode = 401;  
context.Result = result;  
return;
```